# syscolumns table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. When I open master database in SQL Server Management Studio. I can not find syscolumns table under Tables -> System Tables of master database. Where is syscolumns table?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: It's not a table, it's a view.

Comment: Where to find this view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2005, these views are now in the `sys` schema - the one you're looking for is `sys.columns`.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, you'll find those views under (database) -> Views -> System Views.

[image]

See [Understanding Catalog Views in SQL Server 2005/2008](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1934/understanding-catalog-views-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008/) or [MSDN: Querying the SQL Server System Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189082(v=sql.105)) for a few more hints and explanations.